# Null parameter in Json controller method while Jquery parameter has value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am creating a cascading dropdown list based on an example I found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51518.mvc-5-cascading-dropdownlist-using-jquery.aspx)

The query sent to the server to request the second dropdownlist values has non null parameters but when I break in the controller method, it appears empty. As you can see below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks !!

[image: parameter Country is null]
[image: query from Chrome inspector]

It's using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 5 while my project is ASP.NET MVC Core 2

The code in the controller is the following :

```
public JsonResult States(string Country)
{
  List<string> StatesList = new List<string>();
  switch (Country)
  {
     case "India":
       StatesList.Add("New Delhi");
       StatesList.Add("Mumbai");
       StatesList.Add("Kolkata");
       StatesList.Add("Chennai");
       break;
  }
  return Json(StatesList);
}
```

And here is the AJAX :

```
<script src = "/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" > </script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#State").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Country").change(function ()
    {
        if ($("#Country").val() != "Select")
        {
             var CountryOptions = {};
             CountryOptions.url = "/Dropdown/states";
             CountryOptions.type = "POST";
             CountryOptions.data = JSON.stringify({ Country: $("#Country").val() });
             CountryOptions.datatype = "json";
             CountryOptions.contentType = "application/json";
             CountryOptions.success = function (StatesList)
             {
                $("#State").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < StatesList.length; i++)
                {
                     $("#State").append("<option>" + StatesList[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#State").prop("disabled", false);
             };

            CountryOptions.error = function ()
            {
                alert("Error in Getting States!!");
            };
            $.ajax(CountryOptions);
        }
        else
        {
             $("#State").empty();
             $("#State").prop("disabled", true);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try adding the `[FromBody]` parameter to the method - public JsonResult States([[FromBody] string Country)` - but there is no reason to send it as `application/json` - you can just delete the `contentType` option and use `CountryOptions.data = { Country: $("#Country").val() };`

Comment: ^^ That or mark the controller method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke indeed not sending it as `application/json` did the job!

Comment: @Archer, [HttpPost] did not work, but thanks !

Comment: @StephenMuecke any idea why sending it as `application/json` did not work ? In the event I would need to send something as that, I would like to understand what went wrong ^^

Comment: It should have worked if the method is `[HttpPost]` and you use the `[FromBody]` attribute

Comment: The reason it failed when you set the content type to `application/json` is because you also stringified it.  If you left the content type as it was and sent the data as an object it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have specified the `contentType = "application/json"` and are sending stringified data, then you need to add the `[FromBody]` attribute in the POST method to instruct the `ModelBinder` to use the content-type header to determine the `IInputFormatter` to use for reading the request (which for json is the `JsonInputFormatter`). Change the signature of the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult States([FromBody]string Country)
```

However, it is not necessary send the data as json, and you can use the default `contentType` (`'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`). You can delete the `contentType` option and use

```
CountryOptions.data = { Country: $("#Country").val() }; // not stringified
// CountryOptions.contentType = "application/json";
```

For more information, refer [Model binding JSON POSTs in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/).